# Measure various App Engine Statistics

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How we can measure app statistics like CPU Seconds Used/Second, which we are able to see on our dashboard for our App in Google App Engine. (Datastore statistics can be measured using https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/stats, thus similar things exist for other attributes ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quota service API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/quota/package-summary.html) is probably the closest to what you're looking for.

Comment: I also want to measure Request/Seconds and Instances used per second, and other such attributes which are available on our Dashboard.

Comment: Yes, "If all instructions were to be executed sequentially on a standard 1.2 GHz 64-bit x86 CPU, 1200 megacycles would equate to one second physical time elapsed"

Comment: For request-based usage see [Responses section](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Responses) of App Engine Java runtime (e.g `X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage` header)

Comment: Can I measure datastore write operations quota for my application ?